# How do I create separate versions of lambda functions through terraform?

Tags: aws-lambda, versioning

I'm Running Terraform v0.11.14

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename         = "lambda_function.zip"
  function_name    = "test_lambda"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda_tf.arn}"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime          = "python2.7"
  version          = "1"
}
```

On plan I get the error

```
Error: aws_lambda_function.test_lambda: "version": this field cannot be set
```

I couldn't find an aws_lambda_function_version resorce so presume you create versions using the lambda fuction resorce and specifying the version.

I'm not sure what value I give to version to build versions of my lambda.

Im tring to get it to work for one version for now as a first step. I plan on adding count to create multiple versions as my next step if I can get it to create one version first?

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to set

publish = true

I then enconter another issue for creating seprat versions but finding this answers my initial question